# Default load screens on iOS

Tags: ios

Im making a universal app for iPhone and iPad, both retina and non retina displays.

I've looked around the web for the answer and have found conflicting answers, im not sure why some people say the default image for ipad has to be 2008 (h) rather than 2048.

Anyway, I want to know what Default.pngs I need to include with my app for the load screen. And whether each one is essential or not? Also what name each one should be called?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [launch images section of the iOS Image and Design Guidelines](http://bit.ly/LLEHK1) explains this in detail.

> For **iPhone and iPod touch launch images**, include the status bar
>   region. Create launch images of these sizes:
>
> 320 x 480 pixels 640 x 960 pixels (high resolution)
>
> **For iPad launch images**, do not include the status bar region. Create launch images of
>   these sizes:
>
> - For portrait:
>
>   - 768 x 1004 pixels
>   - 1536 x 2008 pixels (high resolution)
> - For landscape:
>
>   - 1024 x 748 pixels
>   - 2048 x 1496 pixels (high resolution)

I also had to ask this [question on ux.stackexchange.com](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22974/designing-an-app-for-ipad-iphone-retina-display) recently, but found the above link later.

---

EDIT: Naming of these files is described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12). Important parts from the text are following:

> Every app must provide at least one launch image. This image is
>   typically in a file named **Default.png** that displays your app’s initial
>   screen in a portrait orientation. However, you can also provide other
>   launch images to be used under different launch conditions. All launch
>   images must be PNG files and must reside in the top level of your
>   app’s bundle directory. The name of each launch image indicates when
>   it is to be used, and the basic format for launch image filenames is
>   as follows:
>
> **`<basename><usage_specific_modifiers><scale_modifier><device_modifier>.png`**

Comment: But what are the naming conventions and which ones do I need, do I need one for portrait upside down, a different one for each landscape?

Comment: @user1013512 I have added the information you asked for to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

[App Store Required Resources - App Launch (Default) Images (Last updated: 2012-03-07)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12)

While searching for the standards, try to search developer.apple.com in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Here is all the information you should need.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12

As for the reason the iPad image is shortened its because of the status bar.